# Calculadora de python :/

Tags: python

recién inicio en la programación y pues, estaba intentando hacer una calculadora para números complejos, operaciones básicas, con puras funciones y que no acepte la división entre cero pero cuando ejecuto la calculadora, no me aparece nada.

Intento definir variable

```
def variables():

    n1 = complex(input("Escriba el primer número: "))
    n2 = complex(input("Escriba el segundo número: "))
```

Luego las operaciones básicas

```
def sumar(n1, n2):

    suma=n1+n2
    print("El resultado es: ",suma)

def restar(n1, n2):

    resta = n1 - n2
    print("El resultado es: ",resta)

def multiplicar(n1, n2):

    multiplicacion = n1 * n2
    print("El resultado es: ",multiplicacion)

def dividir(n1, n2):

    while (n2 == 0):
        n2 = int(input("No se puede dividir entre cero. Inserta otro numero: "))
    division = n1 / n2
    print("El resultado es: ",division)
```

Lo que sería el menú de opciones

```
def menu():

    print("Opciones")
    print("1. Suma")
    print("2. Resta")
    print("3. Multiplicación")
    print("4. División")

def numeros(opcion):

    if(opcion == 1):
        return sumar
    elif(opcion == 2):
        return restar
    elif(opcion == 3):
        return multiplicar
    elif(opcion == 4):
        return dividir

def opciones():
    opcion = int(input("Seleccione una opcion: "))
```

Finalmente intento llamar a todas las funciones

```
if _name_ == "_main_":

    variables()
    menu()
    opciones()
    numeros(opcion)
```

Cuando ejecuto, el código parece estar bien hasta la parte en la que debería salir el resultado, pero no aparece nada.
Soy muy nuevo en esto, ayuda por favor :c

Comment: Todo este código tiene problemas de indentación. los `def metodo():` deben estar en un nivel diferente que "la implementación" del método. Como lo tienes, tienen una implementación vacía. Revisa los básicos de Python y prueba de nuevo :)

Comment: Lamento el error al transcribir el código @Alfabravo, ahora ya está como lo tengo en la consola :c

Comment: Eso es todo lo que tienes? Recuerda que `opcion` debe ser una variable global para que puedas usarla fuera de la función. Como sugerencia, podrías combinar `menu`, `numeros` y `opciones` en una sola función.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes varios problemas en tu codigo, te explico por partes.

Primero, dentro del `if`. Tanto `__name__` como `'__main__'` se escriben con dos barrabajas tanto delante como detras "__" devido a que son variables especiales de Python y las variables especiales se escriben asi.

Tambien te falta recoger los valores que metes en `n1` y `n2` dentro de la funcion `variables()`. Para esto tendrais que retornar los valores porque son variables locales de la funcion `variables()` y no se pueden usar fuera de esta funcion, porque son `undefined`.

La variable `opcion` que estas pasando a la funcion `numeros()` es `undefined`, dado a que es una variable local de la funcion `opciones()` y al igual que en la funcion `variables()` debes retornar su valor para utilizarlo fuera de esta funcion.

Tendrias que cambiar el `if` que tienes de:

```py
if _name_ == "_main_":
    variables()
    menu()
    opciones()
    numeros(opcion)
```

a:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    n1, n2 = variables()
    menu()
    opcion = opciones()
    numeros(opcion)
```

La funcion `variables()` pasaria de:

```py
def variables():
    n1 = complex(input("Escriba el primer número: "))
    n2 = complex(input("Escriba el segundo número: "))
```

a:

```py
def variables():
    n1 = complex(input("Escriba el primer número: "))
    n2 = complex(input("Escriba el segundo número: "))
    return (n1, n2)
```

Algo parecido a `variables()` se hace en la funcion `opciones()`, pasando de:

```py
def opciones():
    opcion = int(input("Seleccione una opcion: "))
```

a:

```py
def opciones():
    opcion = int(input("Seleccione una opcion: "))
    return opcion
```

Por ultimo la funcion `numeros()`. Las funciones `sumar()`, `restar()`, `multiplicar()` y `dividir()` realizan un `print()`, por lo que cuando las llamas no tendran ningun valor y dentro de la funcion `numeros()` estas haciendo un return de lo que te devuelven las funciones estas, lo cual es `undefined` y es absurdo, por lo que quitamos todos los `return`.

Has definido las funciones `sumar()`, `restar()`, `multiplicar()` y `dividir()` con las variables `n1` y `n2`, lo que te obliga a añadirnas en las llamadas a estas funciones. Pero al tenerlas definidas con el `return` dentro del `if` como variables globales podrias no añadirlas a la definicion de la funcion y tampoco pasarlas en su llamada. En mi caso voy a añadirlas a las llamadas para que no haya mucho cambio, en caso de que no entiendas a que me refiero dime en un comentario y te pongo todo el codigo de ambas.

Por lo tanto tu funcion `numeros()` cambiaria de:

```py
def numeros(opcion):
    if(opcion == 1):
        return sumar
    elif(opcion == 2):
        return restar
    elif(opcion == 3):
        return multiplicar
    elif(opcion == 4):
        return dividir
```

a:

```py
def numeros(opcion):
    if(opcion == 1):
        sumar(n1, n2)
    elif(opcion == 2):
        restar(n1, n2)
    elif(opcion == 3):
        multiplicar(n1, n2)
    elif(opcion == 4):
        dividir(n1, n2)
```

Con esto ya funcionaria tu codigo, lo que escribe entre parentesis es un numero `complex`, ya que estas definiendo asi `n1` y `n2`, pero el resultado esta bien.

---

Como extras, te diria que añadieras una validacion para que `opcion` no pueda ser mayor que 4, ya que tu en el elif solo contemblas estas opciones. Esto lo puedes hacer añadiendo una excepcion por ejemplo (Aunque esto es algo quiza ya mas avanzado) o diciendo al usuario que no es una opcion valida, añadiendo un else.

Por otro lado, he querido tocar el codigo lo minimo posible, pero dentro del `if` en la llamada a la funcion `numeros()`, yo añadiria tanto `n1` como `n2` y por ende, debes añadirlos tambien a la definicion de la funcion.

Por ultimo, desconozco que es un numero complejo en python, nunca habia visto ni utilizado por ello yo directamente ni los usaria, pero esto ya es algo personal.

---

Ten cuidado con este tipo de cosas que te he corregido y animo con la programacion, de los errores se aprende y para la proxima no los cometeras!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya funcionó la calculadora con los cambios que sugeriste :3

Comment: @Raúl Si la respuesta te ha servido, márcala como buena para que otra persona que tenga tu misma duda vea la respuesta y además de esta manera la pregunta no se quedara pendiente.